# How to solve sequelize migration duplicate entry

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, database-migration, feathersjs

How to solve sequelize migration duplicate entry. I have a migration script created to restrict duplicate entries in the database this will set contraints that no duplicate file with the same filename that will be added. Now since there are already duplicate data on the database which is existing specially in staging I receive and error .

How do I will solve since there are already duplicate data on staging ? should I pull a database from staging and import on my local and manually delete the dups ? and then run the migration ?

#Errors

```
UniqueConstraintError [SequelizeUniqueConstraintError]: Validation error
  name: 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError',
 code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY',
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way.
Either you delete duplicated rows or you don't add an unique constraint.
Maybe you can add an SQL query that deletes duplicates in the same migration where the unique constraint is created to ensure that there will be no duplicates at the moment when you add the unique constraint.

Comment: can you give an example query sir that will delete all duplicates ? ,  i have a query that selects all duplicates

Comment: like for example I want to delete all records with duplicate or with the same filename